# "I bought apples." vs "I bought some apples."

Tags: difference, determiners

"I bought apples." vs "I bought some apples."

Is the first sentence grammatical? If yes, is there any difference in meaning between the two?

Somehow I feel that if I am asked "What did you do yesterday?", "I bought some apples" sounds better than "I bought apples". Am I mistaken? On the other hand, if I am asked "What did you buy?", then "I bought apples" sounds fine to me.

Comment: Both are fine and are interchangeable in general usage.   To address your second question, buying 'some apples' seems to imply a normal amount commensurate with a domestic shopping trip.  However, the supply chain manager of a large warehouse might be inclined to say 'I buy apples'.

Comment: so "some apples" is more likely to be used with a specific action while "buy apples" is with a pattern?

Comment: No, you can say 'today I bought apples' and that may have been the first time ever.  Adding 'some' is just more colloquial and less formal, suited to verbal dialogue.  You will see both and there is no definite right or wrong.

Comment: This question has been asked several times, I think. But there is no need to downvote people without a good reason.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, but then someone should say that to the OP. Or, we can just be mean.

Comment: @Mari-LouA would you please provide a link to a reference that clarifies their difference (if any) in connotation?

Comment: The same difference as saying "I bought a few apples" You should look "a few" up . If someone said "I bought [some/a few] apples" No one is going to interpret each one differently.  Although I have to say Murray's comment above was thoughtful.

Comment: Thanks! But somehow I feel that if I am asked "What did you do yesterday?", "I bought some apples" sounds better than "I bought apples". Am I mistaken? On the other hand, if I am asked "What did you buy?", then "I bought apples" sounds fine to me.

Comment: You should add that reflection in the question. It's a valid observation. Why do so many questions on ELL limit themselves by asking if something is correct or sounds natural? Explaining why you (plural meaning) think it maybe wrong, or not goes a long way to making a question more interesting and potentially more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

From a connotation standpoint, I would use the first if apples were on the family shopping list: "I bought apples" means that that particular item (apples) can be crossed off of the shopping list.

"I bought some apples" connotes a more impromptu motive: I was at the store for something else, apples caught my eye, so I bought some.

These are anecdotal examples of differences, but perhaps others can support or refute this interpretation.

Comment: +1 for usage in context.

Comment: Some could also be used to stress that you didn't get the amount or variety that was expected. "Did you get the apples to make cider?" "I got some apples, but they only had 5kg. I'll go to the other shop tomorrow and get more". "Did you get the apples to make apple tart?" "I got some apples, but they didn't have any Granny Smith. See if the ones I bought are OK instead"