# 'Some' is a mandatory word?

Tags: ellipsis, plural-forms, formal-language

The well-known book English Grammar in Use [for intermediate] p.143 give this exercise choice:

> I went to the library and borrowed books/some books.

The book answer (some books):

> I went to the library and borrowed some books.

1. If 'some' is not a mandatory word, then why is the sentence without 'some' wrong?

**Edit:**

2. What is the difference in meaning between 2 options above?

**Edit 2:**
This question is different from the [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/251919/i-bought-apples-vs-i-bought-some-apples): I buy some apples/apples in the shop, because the main purpose (product) of the library is books versus a shop that contains different types of products.

Comment: *The sentence without 'some' is **not** wrong!* It's syntactically fine - just not very idiomatic in that *exact* context. But it's perfectly natural with or without 'some' in, say, *I went to the shop and bought [some] cigarettes.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, agree—this is the question.

Comment: Note that ***some*** nearly always implies ***not all***. So arguably it makes more sense to qualify the "borrowed books" as being only a *fraction* of all the books in the library (as might be implied if the determiner was ***the*** rather than ***some***). And arguably the justification for a determiner is greater when the actual noun conveys very little information (as in your example, since there's not really anything *else* you might borrow from a library). Which is different to ***my*** example, since I could have bought bread, milk, or whatever, rather than cigarettes.

Comment: Also [“get drinks” and “get some drinks” vs. “get the drinks”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229279/get-drinks-and-get-some-drinks-vs-get-the-drinks) And doubtless several more, but it's not easy to actually *search* for duplicates asking about this particular aspect of usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, please see my edit 2.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your edit. I made the point in my comment that ***some** Xs* works better than the "zero article" in contexts where ***Xs*** are the only likely noun (you wouldn't ***borrow [some] cigarettes*** from the library, for example). I think that's really all you need to know to "explain" why you'd normally borrow ***some*** books from the library.

Comment: Without a qualifier, you'd be forced to think that the subject borrowed ALL the books. That's why you need *some*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex  I strongly disagree, see my answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel You know, I never know what to do when people tell me they disagree with me. Uhm, that's cool, I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - I went to the library and borrowed some books.
> - I went to the library and borrowed books.

Both of these are perfectly grammatical and normal. A fluent speaker might say or write either. There is no significant difference in meaning. The first version, with "some" is more common, at least in my experience. This way of omitting an article, sometimes referred to as "using the zero article" is, I think more common than it used to be, but many people prefer to stick with older and more familiar forms. Which form is favored seems to vary by the exact situation.

> - I went to the store and bought groceries.
> - I went to the store and bought some groceries.

I think the version without some is more common. The idea that omitting "some" suggests that the person bought all the groceries in the store or borrowed all the books in the library is absurd. Common sense tells one othewise, and in any case a zero article does not imply "all the".

> - I went to the library and borrowed **the** books.

might be taken to imply all the books in the library, but more likely it refers to some specific group of books previously mentioned, as in:

> My teacher gave me a list of books to read on this subject. I went to the library and borrowed **the** books.

Here it clearly means the books on the list, and no others.